# AWS Lightsail: Is there a way to visit my web server using a non-ip or custom domain server URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, url, uri

I don't want to use a custom domain name, and I don't want to use a purely numeric IP address, Instead I want to be able to something like //amazonaws.com/usa-east-1/myinstancename/.

Is there a URI pattern I can use that will allow this?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Your computer needs to make a connection with an IP address. This IP address can either be specified directly, or it can be discovered via a DNS Name (which is the first part of a URL).

When using Amazon EC2, a URL is provided that has a DNS name that directly maps to an IP address, such as:

```
ec2-12-34-56-78.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

However, I don't think that Amazon Lightsail provides this.